# Dynamica Package for Mathematica

Tags: packages

I have been trying to download the package *Dynamica* for *Mathematica*, included with *Discrete Dynamical Systems and Difference Equations with Mathematica*, 
by *Mustafa R.S. Kulenovic* and *Orlando Merino*. The package offers numerical tools for the study of continuous and discrete dynamical systems, such as computation of invariant manifolds, phase space tools etc.

Problem is that I am not able to find it online and I am not aware of any other packages doing that. 
Any help?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

It seems that the file cannot be downloaded from people outside the US, because of the server. I have already contacted the authors, but it would be of great help if a person who is able to download the file could then share it.

Thank you again.

Comment: Are you sure you tried? I googled *dynamica mathematica package* and found this: http://www.math.uri.edu/Dynamica/ as **first result**.

Comment: Yeap, it wont download. Server will not respond.

Comment: It downloads fine here.

Comment: Can you please send it to me? I am not able to download it. You tried on the latest one? The one from 2014?

Comment: It might be easier you write the authors a mail: kulenm@math.uri.edu or merino@math.uri.edu

Comment: Have already done that, but it takes longer than expected. I just need it by tonight in order to prepare a presentation. After all it is free to download.

Comment: Would it be possible that someone downloads it for me since I get an error "connection timed out", while other people can apparently download it.

Comment: It won't download for me either; you should definitely contact the authors.

Comment: I think your problem is that the download link is a *ftp address* (they never work on my windows 8.1), so **try this:** right click on the link, select *save destination as...* and choose your download folder. This should work (it does for me).

Comment: As another workaround, you could download and install and add-on for you browser like: https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/fireftp/ (this is for Firefox) that provide access to *ftp* servers.

Comment: @mattiav27 Well I gave it a shot with both Chrome and Firefox. On the first one it would not even open the "Save as.." option. Firefox did a bit better, until the .zip download failed. Also the add-on did not seem to do actually anything :/.How would it be able for you to download it by doing the same steps?

Comment: Do you still need this?

Comment: @RunnyKine Sure it would be great!

Comment: Is it possible that you sent it by mail? It's a .zip so it should be possible.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thank you so much!

Comment: I have just sent it to you.

Comment: @RunnyKine I received it and I am already working with it! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: 404 as of 20 Dec 2018. Page does not exist. Anyone willing to share a copy with me?

Comment: The book but not the package is found at wolfram. http://library.wolfram.com/search/?query=dynamica&collection=library&x=0&y=0.  Still haven't found the package files.